# Create shortcode in Child Theme?

Tags: shortcode, child-theme

I have created a child theme, and I am trying to add a shortcode to its functions.php file, by doing this:

```
// functions.php of child theme

<?php 

include(WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/graduates_functions.php');

?>

// graduates_functions.php

<?php

// [bartag foo="foo-value"]
function sayhi_func( $atts ) {

    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'graduate_type' => 'seo',
        'bar' => 'something else',
    ), $atts ) );
    echo 'test';
}

add_shortcode( 'sayhi', 'sayhi_func' );

?>
```

But when doing [sayhi] from a page I don't see the echo, I see [sayhi]. It works if I add the same in the functions.php of the theme itself, not the child.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Its worth a second look, but it sounds like you do not have the child theme enabled.

Comment: where the graduates_functions.php is saved?

Comment: ... and what is in `graduates_functions.php`? Is that part of your theme or the parent?

Comment: I have the same problem

Answer (score 1):

Shortcodes don't 'echo', they need to 'return' something. So I guess it will work if you put your functions content between ob_start and ob_get_clean so you return everything inbetween:

`function yourfunction(){ ob_start(); /* insert here the code of your function */  $output = ob_get_clean(); return $output; }`